# R: Plot grouped coordinates on world map

Tags: string, r, dictionary, legend

I would like to plot a set of coordinates organized in studies/groups on a world map, specified in a legend. The dataset is organized as follows: AUTHORS | LAT | LONG
The are multiple coordinates corresponding to one study that do not differ. 
Is it possible to plot numbers instead of symbols and link them to a legend?

```
library(maps) 
library(mapdata)

test<-data.frame(Authors=(letters[1:9]), LAT=(seq(10,90,by=10)), LONG=(seq(10,90,by=10)))
map('worldHires') 
points(test$LONG,test$LAT, col="red")
```

I have no clue how to extract the info from the authors vector and link it to the lat/long data as part of a legend. Does it even work with `points` ?

Comment: If I were you I would  include some code to show [what you have already tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and ensure that your example code is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381). This is very vague as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(maps) 
library(mapdata)

test<-data.frame(Authors=(letters[1:9]), LAT=runif(9,-90,90), LONG=runif(9,-180,180))
map('worldHires') 
text(test$LONG,test$LAT,labels=1:9, col="red", font=2)
legend("bottom",legend=test$Authors, col="red", pch=as.character(1:9), bg="white", ncol=3)
```

Use `text` instead of `points` (you can use `points` but you will have to choose `pch=as.character(1:9)`). Here I added argument `font=2` so that they appear in bold which makes them more legible.
Then creating the legend is fairly straight-forward.

[image]