# R ggmap Error: object 'f' not found

Tags: r, ggmap, rnoaa

After I install `rnoaa` packages, my `ggmap` package is not working.  I couldn't even do the simple example:

```
>library(ggmap)

>qmap(location = "boston university")
```

> > Error in get("f", environment(CoordMap$train)) : object 'f' not found

Does anyone have the same problem? Thank you!

Comment: @bethanyP I did reproduce the error with those 2 lines of code, although I'm unclear as to why it's happening. Even the following example from the `ggmap` help page for the `get_map` function doesn't work: `map <- get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 6, source = "stamen")`. 
`ggmap(map, fullpage = TRUE)`

Comment: Code works fine for me. Close R, reopen and try again. Then load extra libraries one by one and test after each

Comment: This is just a simple example that you don't need any data.  @bethanyP

Comment: I even reinstall R, R studio and all packages, it still shows the error. @RichardTelford

Comment: I just ran it too...it loads a map fine..

Answer (score 5):

Reverting to ggplot v. 2.2.0 worked for me:  `devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2@v2.2.0")`

Answer (score 1):

1. Reinstall R and R Studio
2. `Library(devtools)
    devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
    devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`

Had the same error, and works fine now.

Comment: This is the best answer for most cases. Dont' revert to older versions, just update both ggmap and ggplot to their newest releases on github

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, uninstalling ggplot2 and reinstalling it from CRAN worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague fix this problem by installing the old version of ggmap. ggmap updated on 2016-01-23. The old version from 2015-12-19 works fine. For those who have the same problem, go to link below and download the old version of ggmap. It should fix the problem.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem with ggmap not working. Using the CRAN package "version", I saw that my installed version was 2.6.1, claimed by CRAN to be the latest version. But on GitHub I discovered version 2.7, downloaded it with devtools, and now my code is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688270/ggplot-not-plotting-ggmap-object/41722944#41722944) and reinstall the packages again.It should solve the problem.