# ggmap ggplot2 map error

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have been encountering issues with ggmap.  I am running code that worked a few weeks ago.  Now I receive the error "Error in get("f", environment(CoordMap$train)) : object 'f' not found"  I have restarted R and updated it as well.  I have tried uploading older versions of ggplot2 and ggmap.

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
```

Here is my map code.

```
CenterOfMap <- geocode("39.805157, -122.557298")
California <- get_map(c(lon=CenterOfMap$lon, lat=CenterOfMap$lat), zoom=6, maptype = "satellite", source="google")
CaliforniaMap <- ggmap(California)
CaliforniaMap
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: sounds like you're having similar issues as a [few others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41947045/5977215) - might need to go back to an older version of ggplot2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R ggmap Error: object 'f' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886948/r-ggmap-error-object-f-not-found)