# Error When Trying To Plot Coordinates in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I wanted to plot coordinates from a dataset onto a map, I used the code I found from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130604/plot-coordinates-on-map). My code looked like this:

```
# creating a sample data.frame with your lat/lon points
lon <- c(known_long_lat$takeoff.longitude)
lat <- c(known_long_lat$takeoff.latitude)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# getting the map
mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(df$lon), lat = mean(df$lat)), zoom = 4, maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

# plotting the map with some points on it
ggmap(mapgilbert) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), 
size = 5, shape = 21) +
guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)`
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> Error in if (lon < -180 || lon > 180) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In mean.default(df$lon) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>   2: In mean.default(df$lat) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I thought maybe it was because I had non-numeric data in the latitude and longitude columns but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: can you share some data, it might be that some data falls outside the range (-180/180)

Comment: Check the output of `mean(df$lon)` and `mean(df$lat)`, they seem to be NA. You probably need `mean(df$lon, na.rm = T)`

Comment: It turns out that I did have non-numeric values in the longitude column as I had only checked the latitude column. But now when I run it I get Warning message:
In cbind(lon, lat) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: if you remove NAs from lon, your lat and lon vectors are not the same length when binding them. Easiest is to use `mean(lon,na.rm=T)` and `mean(lat,na.rm=T)` as input to `get_map`

Comment: I manually made a smaller version of my dataset and when I could make sure there was nothing wrong I no longer get that error. Unfortunately I'm having a different problem where it's removing rows that it says are containing missing values although all the longitudes and latitudes are definitely there.

Comment: Fixed that last error I had, I just had my zoom set wrong